# Overriding vs Overloading in JAVA inheritance

Tags: java, overriding

Give code:

```
class Foo{
    public String toString(Foo foo){return " Foo";}

    public void printMe(){System.out.print(this.toString(this));}
}

class Bar extends Foo{        
    public String toString(Bar bar){return " Bar";}
}

class MyClass{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Foo baz = new Bar();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.foo.printMe();
        m.bar.printMe();
        m.baz.printMe();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Foo Foo Foo
```

Please, explain why it's not called Bar.toString() through bar-reference?

Answer (score 2):

It simply because jvm first check method binding in subclass if not found then check in superclass.

```
1) Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Foo has printMe()

```
2) Bar bar = new Bar();
```

Bar does not have printMe() so jvm call Foo's method

```
3) Foo baz = new Bar();
```

Bar does not have printMe() so jvm call Foo's method

And in `printMe()` method it always call Foo's `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Bar` class has two `toString(argument)` methods. It has `toString(Bar)` and `toString(Foo)`.

When you call `this.toString(this)` from inside `Foo`, the compiler knows that `this` is a `Foo`. (At Runtime it will sometimes be a `Bar`, but that is not the compiler's concern.) So when it figures out what `toString(this)` means, it decides it must mean `toString(Foo)`. It couldn't possibly decide it meant `toString(Bar)` because firstly, it doesn't know `this` is a `Bar`, and secondly, it can't call `Bar` instance methods inside `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`printMe()` is called as a member of `Foo`.
Thus it can only access functions and fields declared by `Foo`.
This means that `printMe()` calls `Foo`'s `toString()` and prints `Foo`.